# Haskell help with . and $

Tags: function, haskell, composition

As an example, take the following

```
type Row a = [a]
type Table a = [Row a]

mapTable :: (a -> b) -> Table a -> Table b
mapTable = map . map

notTable :: Table Bool -> Table Bool
notTable = map . map $ (not)
```

Why, if I remove the $ from notTable, does it stop working?

I have explained this to myself a few times, but it never sticks and it takes me awhile to reason through whats going on. I know the $ basically makes sure that each side of the $ gets evaluated separately because the $ has the lowest precedence but why does this break if I pull the $ out?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right about precedence: `.` is infixr 9 (9 is highest), while `$` is infixr 0 (0 is lowest).  See the [Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.4.2) for the operator fixity table.

However, function application has higher precedence than any operator, even `.` .  Hence:

```
map . map $ (not)
```

becomes:

```
(map . map) $ (not)
```

while

```
map . map (not)
```

becomes:

```
map . (map not)
```

Comment: Ok, I'm with you this far. But I need one step more to get the "light bulb" moment I think. I am having a hard time seeing why `map . (map not)` doesn't work. Is it because if you were to pass a Table to it, it would apply `map not` to it, then you would be trying to apply map to just a Table with no function to map? ... Great, I think that makes sense to me... but I now I don't see why `map . map (not)` works. I can never seem to understand both sides at once. :) Thanks again.

Comment: `map . map (not)` doesn't work. `map . map $ (not)` (equivalently, `map . map $ not`) works.

Comment: Try going into ghci and doing ":type map . (map not)" and the other variants from here.

Comment: Oops, yeah, that was a typo. I  know `map . map (not)` does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Re the question you asked as a comment to Joey Adams' answer: "Why does `map . map $ not = (map . map) $ not` work, while `map . map not = map . (map not)` doesn't?"

Let us first consider what `map . map` does. First of all, `map` takes a function `f :: a -> b` and a list with type `[a]`, giving a list with type `[b]` where `f` is applied to each element of the original list. The type of `map` is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. Recall that in Haskell, this means that `map` really is a function that takes a function `a -> b` and returns a function taking an `[a]` and giving a `[b]`. We often like to think of this as `map` being a function of two variables, but the distinction will be important later on.

Now let us consider what the composition operator `(.)` does. Recall that it is defined as

```
(.)  :: (b1 -> c1) -> (a1 -> b1) -> (a1 -> c1)
f . g = \ x -> f (g x)
```

, i.e. it takes two functions `f` and `g` (with suitable domains/inputs and targets/outputs), and gives you a new function defined by first applying `g`  and then applying `f` to whatever `g` spits out. I've called the type variables `a1`, `b1`, and `c1` to avoid confusion later on.

OK, now we're in a position to figure out what `map . map` is. For the sake of clarity, 
let us write the two (identical) maps as

```
mapleft :: (c -> d) -> [c] -> [d]
mapleft = map
mapright :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapright = map
```

Now the way "functions of two variables" are encoded in Haskell becomes important. Since functions in Haskell really just have *one* input, we have to be careful, as discussed above. Thus, the domain/input of of `mapright` is really just of type `a -> b`, while the output is really of type `[a] -> [b]`. Going back to the signature of `(.)`, this means we've fixed the right hand operand's type, `a1 -> b1` above, to be `(a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])`. Thus, `a1 = a -> b` and `b1 = [a] -> [b]`.

Proceding in the same way for the left hand operand, we see that `[a] -> [b] = b1 = c -> d`, so `c = [a]` and `d = [b]`. The same reasoning gives `c1 = [c] -> [d] = [[a]] -> [[b]]`.

And we're done, we can now read off the type of `leftmap .  rightmap = map . map`: It is

```
a1 -> c1 = (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]
```

. This is confirmed by GHCi:

```
Prelude> :t (map . map)
(map . map) :: (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]
```

Now it will become clear why the two functions you talk about are different. Clearly, `(map . map) not` has type `[[Bool]] -> [[Bool]]`, which is exactly what you want. `map not`, on the other hand, has type `[Bool] -> [Bool]`. Taking the output of `map not` and feeding it into the (*first*) input of `map` will not even typecheck: The first input of `map` has to be a *function*, while the output of `map not` is a `[Bool]`.

Comment: Thanks, that is just what I was looking for in response to my question. Hopefully after I come back to this post a few times to remember how this works it will stick for good. :)

Answer (score 2):

Function application binds very tightly, so without `$` it parses as `map . (map not)` rather than `(map . map) not`, which is the interpretation you want.